# Google OAuth and Offline access

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have successfully implemented "Login with Google" feature and everything works perfectly but I would like to add one extra feature - "Disconnect Your Google Account".

I can easily remove a row from "auth" table (user_id, source, source_id) but I would like to remove it from:
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

too!

I guess I have to use a PHP client library for accessing Google APIs: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

And that's okay. But I'm not sure about sending GET and POST requests - when user is logging first time I can save in my database data such as:

```
   (
        [access_token] => MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
        [token_type] => Bearer
        [expires_in] => 3599
        [id_token] => MY_ID_TOKEN
    )
```

But what about expiring? They don't login everytime - they will be logged for couple of weeks or even months and that means my token data can expired?

Thank you.

Comment: try $client->getAuth()->revokeToken($token);  but I am not sure I think it only works on an access token.